# Avoid html() replace existing elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using .html() method to add multiple images to a div.

```
$('#info').html('<img class="catalog/chair.jgp"/><img class="catalog/chair2.jgp"/>');
```

But it replaces the existing elements of the div and adds the new images/content.

How do I add the image instead of replacing the elements which already exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's where `.append()/.prepend()` is used:

```
$('#info').append('<img class="catalog/chair.jgp"/><img class="catalog/chair2.jgp"/>');
```

and even you want to use it with `.html()` then you have to concatenate with the old html before replacing:

```
var $html = $('#info').html()+'<img class="catalog/chair.jgp"/><img class="catalog/chair2.jgp"/>'
$('#info').html($html);
```

Comment: That's the type of answer I was waiting for. Covers all. Thanks. +10

Comment: You are welcome @Becky.

Answer (score 1):

Use `append()` instead.

```
$('#info').append('<img class="catalog/chair.jgp"/><img class="catalog/chair2.jgp"/>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) the HTML.

Like this.

```
$('#info').append('<img class="catalog/chair.jgp"/><img class="catalog/chair2.jgp"/>');
```

Answer (score 0):

In plain JS

```
var img = document.createElement( 'img' )
img.src = 'catalog/chair.jpg'
document.getElementById( 'info' ).appendChild( img )
```

jQuery of course has its own confusing quirks on how to do something very standard (it probably has a shorter-hand version as well, I've no idea, I try to avoid it)

```
var img = $( '<img>' )
img.attr( 'src', 'catalog/chair.jpg' )
img.appendTo( '#info' )
```

Answer (score 0):

just try [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

unless you really know what is your doing, careful use html("")(not html())